# Animate gives errors when I also use bigfoot or cprotect

Tags: errors, animate, bigfoot

I get some errors trying to use the `animate` package with the `cprotect` or/and `bigfoot` packages.

When I use the `cprotect` package in:

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{bigfoot} 
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
            \inaccessible 
l.18848   \cs_set_nopar:Npn ^^L
                            { }
```

When instead I use the `bigfoot` package, I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@abspage already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.56   \newcounter{abspage}
                       %
```

Is there a way to correct one or both of these errors?

The contents of the `.log` file after using `\listfiles` are available [here](http://pastebin.com/EY8hu6ig).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error with `bigfoot` has nothing to do with `cprotect`; just load `bigfoot` after `animate`.

The following document raises no error:

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Many thanks! Loading `bigfoot` and `cprotect` after `animate` fixes both problems, even with my old  Arch-provided TeXLive. After upgrading it I can also have `cprotect` before `animate` exactly as you write.